# Button getting out of the screen android layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I got this relativelayout and on the design screen of android studio looks good

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sEJH.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context="com.checking.movi.movioperations.CartItems">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcartprod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Productos seleccionados:"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="649dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcartprod"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_placeorder"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:text="Continuar"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I test on the phone the button gets out of the screen if I decrease the size of the recyclerview it does appear can you guys give me a little help with this don't know to tell it to keep the 3 on the same screen

Comment: Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the Button. Use `android: layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_above="<button_id>"` for the recycler view.

Comment: OK ashu I will try it once I get back let you know outcome thank you

Comment: Hello Ashu the answer from tuqay is the same as yours so it is working great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving width and height to `view`s in dp's (or pixels) isn't the correct way. Because screen size isn't the same in all devices. Your design tab at Android Studio shows your layout in Pixel phone whose height is greater than your mobile phones. So, you can't see that button in your mobile phone.

I have added one line to your button and deleted another

Added this:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Deleted this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/txtcartprod"
```

Changed height of `RecyclerView` to `match_parent` (to make it depend on screen size):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And added this line:

```
android:layout_above= "@id/btn_placeorder"
```

**Final version**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context="com.checking.movi.movioperations.CartItems">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcartprod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Productos seleccionados:"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above= "@id/btn_placeorder"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcartprod"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_placeorder"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:text="Continuar"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you understood all the changes I made. If you have difficulty, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Thanks tuqay sure will try this out

Comment: Thank you Tuqay it worked great, you are right I should not put fixed pixel size because it depends on screen sizes, did the changes you suggested and now button appears regards